# get data from a object

Tags: javascript, jquery

on some places i need the values from data-tags in a tr:

```
<tr data-something="1234" data-somethingmore="56789">
    <td>blabla</td>
    <td><img src="edit"></td>
</tr>
```

I am using the following click-Event that i open a jquery-ui-dialog. This works very good but I need the same data-tags from a other table with the same description in the data array for open the same dialog.

```
$( "#artikelposition" )
    .on( "click", "img", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = [];

        data['something']               = $( this ).closest( "tr" ).data( "something" );
        data['somethingmore']           = $( this ).closest( "tr" ).data( "somethingmore" );
        openDialogArticle( data, "edit");

    });
```

I have added the following function:

```
function getArticleData( tablerow )
{
    var data = [];

    data['something']             = tablerow.data( "something" );
    data['somethingmore']         = tablerow.data( "somethingmore" );
    console.log( tablerow );
    console.log( "from function: " + data );

}


$( "#artikelposition" )
    .on( "click", "img", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        getArticleData( $( this ).closest( "tr" ), "edit"  );

        openDialogArticle( data, "edit");

    });
```

and now the data is empty

how can i get the datatags from the tablerow-object? the console.log( tablerow ) print the object.

Comment: Define this data array  `var data = [];` outside `getArticleData()` function, so that its accessible over here `openDialogArticle( data, "edit");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have set your variable `data` local to the `getArticleData` function so if you want to use it you need to return it at the end of your function:

```
function getArticleData( tablerow )
{
    var data = [];

    data['something']             = tablerow.data( "something" );
    data['somethingmore']         = tablerow.data( "somethingmore" );
    console.log( tablerow );
    console.log( "from function: " + data );

    return data;
}
```

And then in your click function:

```
$( "#artikelposition" ).on( "click", "img", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = getArticleData($( this ).closest( "tr" ));

    openDialogArticle( data, "edit");
});
```

Please note I have removed the `"edit"` as your `getArticleData` function is only expecting the table row